# Apache commons configuration regex expression interpretation

Tags: java, properties

On my current project, we use apache commons configuration to read configuration files for our applications and tests.

I've noticed a peculiar behaviour with the regular expressions in the configuration files.

We have a property with a regex so we can find the correct files in the input folders, for example:

```
FILE_PATTERN = (xpto(\d{3})).input
```

This will find all files which name starts with xpto followed by 3 digits, for example xpto001.input.

The problem is that in some systems this expression works, while in others with exactly the same libs it requires the \d to be escaped, it only works like:

```
FILE_PATTERN = (xpto(\\d{3})).input
```

I've read the documentation of the apache commons configuration and the java properties and I failed to find any configuration/setting that could change this.

Can anyone help me identify what affects this behaviour?

Thank you.